# Не меняются значения переменных

Tags: python, случайные-числа, импорт

Мне нужно создать рандомайзер на 3 числа, но я хочу сделать это в 2 файла, в одном механика рандома, в другом просто импорт и вывод чисел, такой код у меня есть:
вот сама механика

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
spin1 = random.choice(list)
spin2 = random.choice(list)
spin3 = random.choice(list)
data_lotery = {'spin1': spin1, 'spin2': spin2, 'spin3': spin3}
```

а в другом файле это просто выводится
Но при импорте в другой файл, значения не меняются, конечно, можно всю механику запихнуть к выводу, но это не красиво, можете подсказать еще пути решения?

Comment: еще это нужно, чтобы избежать импорта рандома в основной файл

Comment: Внести этот код внутрь функции, которая на вход примет последовательность, а на выходе выдаст нужный словарь или просто три рандомных числа. Потом импортировать где нужно эту функцию и вызывать ее. Если список вариантов статичен, можно хранить его как константу в модуле с функцией. Тогда функция может ничего не принимать на вход, а обращаться напрямую к константе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Для регенерации чисел при каждом запросе к данному файлу, стоит поместить код в функцию.
2. Не следует использовать в качестве имён переменных зарезервированные в языке имена. В данном случае, Вы используете `list`, который является этим самым зарезервированным именем.

Файл, в котором генерируются рандомные числа (`file1.py`):

```
import random 

numbers_list = list( range(0, 10) ) # генерирует список от 0 до 9

def generate_random_numbers():
    spin1 = random.choice(numbers_list)
    spin2 = random.choice(numbers_list)
    spin3 = random.choice(numbers_list)

    data_lotery = {
        "spin1": spin1,
        "spin2": spin2,
        "spin3": spin3,
    }
   
    return data_lotery
```

Файл, в котором данные числа запрашиваются (`file2.py`):

```
from file1 import generate_random_numbers

data_lotery = generate_random_numbers() # запуск функции из первого файла

print(data_lotery) # Вывод полученных из функции чисел
```

Comment: Если нужно брать значение из диапазона целых чисел, то есть random.randint